# Does anyone know if/how you can run PowerShell on Vagrant Win10 VM with a macOS host?

Tags: macos, powershell, vagrant

I'm currently running Mojave 10.14.6 on the host machine, Vagrant 2.2.5, and Virtual box 6.0.10.

I'm running a Win10 Enterprise box and am trying to access Powershell.

I tried the *vagrant powershell* command and received an error stating that the host doesn't support powershell, which makes sense since macOS doesn't natively support powershell.

I also tried to ssh into the box and use the *start powershell* command but it says unknown command.

When I just type *powershell* it shows that the program is there.

Does anyone know how to run powershell?

*edit* this problem is happening in terminal. The gui works fine through virtualbox.

Comment: Windows 10 has PowerShell 5.1 built-in.  It’s unclear why you can’t run a PowerShell within Windows 10?

Comment: It works through the gui via Virtualbox. The issue is it wont work in terminal via Vagrant commands or through ssh.